# Geometric Sequence Complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

[image: I've was just wondering if there were Trigonometry materials where they have really obscu]

Can someone evaluate this? I'm having trouble as I could not get that answer

I get $$-i(\frac{z(z^{44}-1)}{z-1} - \frac{z^{-1}(z^{44}-1)}{z^{-1}-1}) + 1  $$

$$-i(z^{44}-1)\frac{z+1}{z-1} +1$$

since $z=cis(2)$ then $z^{45} = i$ and $z^{44} = \frac{i}{z}$

then I get $$\frac{iz^2+iz+1+z^2}{z^2-z}$$

Can someone spot the mistake??

Comment: Shouldn't the exponent be $-44$ in the second fraction?

Comment: a(r^n-1)/r-1 where n is the number of terms, i also factored out the z44 -1 so i  think its correct

Comment: ,ahh wait sorry it should negative my mistake

Comment: $$-i\Big(\frac{z}{1-z}-\frac{z^{-1}}{1-{z^{-1}}}\Big)=-i\Big(\frac{z+1}{1-z}\Big)=i\Big(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\Big)$$

Comment: How did you find that $z^{45}=i$ and $z^{44}=\frac{i}{z}$? Other than the $z^{-44}$ in the second fraction, I don't see anything wrong with your formula.